How to fix Typescript error with some reactjs-popup example code
The following code (taken from the reactjs-popup documentation) is giving the Typescript error Type '(close: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322) when using the reactjs-popup  component. Other than using a "@ts-ignore" is there a way to address this error?
import React from 'react';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';

const mypopup = () => (
  <div>
    <Popup
      trigger={<button>Information</button>}
      modal
    >
      {close => (
        <div>
          <div>What is this?</div>
          <button onClick={() => { close(); }}>close</button>
        </div>
      )
      }
    </Popup>
  </div>
);


Congrats, you encountered a problem that is not your fault!  This is an oversight in the types for the reactjs-popup package.
You are defining the child of the Popup as a function.  This is supported by the library and included in their docs, which show the use of the "function as children pattern".
But when you look at their TypeScript types, this sort of use is not covered.  The children property of the Popup is defined as:
  children: React.ReactNode;

  //| ((close: () => void, isOpen: boolean) => React.ReactNode);

The type that you need is there in their source code, but it's commented out?!  Very strange.  As it stands, the types say that the children of the Popup can only be a ReactNode and cannot be a function.
You should open an issue in their repo to report this mistake. They have a big banner that the package is looking for maintainers so I would not expect it to get fixed anytime soon.

The Popup component is expecting to have children as React.ReactNode, while it should expect either a callback function (as portrayed in your use-case). A quick fix would be to @ts-ignore, as you suggested, but naturally you would still want type safety.
In that case to get the component working again, you can wrap it in a custom component, where you redeclare the props to expect the correct type.
import { Popup } from "reactjs-popup";
import type { PopupProps } from "reactjs-popup/dist/types";
import "./App.css";

type MyPopupProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode | ((close: () => void, isOpen: boolean) => React.ReactNode);
};

function MyPopup(props: MyPopupProps & Omit<PopupProps, "children">) {
  return <Popup {...(props as PopupProps)} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <MyPopup trigger={<button>Information</button>} modal>
          {(close) => (
            <div className="modal">
              <div>
                Come on ladies
                <br />
                let's get in formation
              </div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  close();
                }}
              >
                close
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </MyPopup>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;




Try the following:
import React from 'react';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';

const PopupContent: React.FC<{ close: () => void }> = ({ close }) => (
  <div>
    <div>What is this?</div>
    <button onClick={close}>close</button>
  </div>
);

const MyPopup: React.FC = () => (
  <div>
    <Popup
      trigger={<button>Information</button>}
      modal
    >
      {close => <PopupContent close={close} />}
    </Popup>
  </div>
);

export default MyPopup;

Define the children as a functional component PopupContent separately and use it within the Popup component:

Your suggested code produces the same Typescript error.
